# Postgresql - Merge field to JSON object in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Hello everyone, I have the following query below which contains a sub query:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, data.permissions, gp.has_permission
FROM groups g
RIGHT JOIN groups_permissions gp ON gp.group_id = g.id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT p.id, array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(p.*)))
FROM permissions p
GROUP BY p.id) AS data (id, permissions) ON (gp.permission_id = data.id)
WHERE g.id=1
```

This query returns the result bellow:

```
[
  {
    "id": "7a588463-1780-459a-9646-8f19e9cb6ded",
    "name": "Administradores",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "id": "bf9d5ee3-d554-4faa-9cf4-9c60acb79801",
        "name": "Criar Grupos",
        "slug": "criar-grupos",
        "created_at": "2020-12-07T00:50:05.017783",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-07T00:50:05.017783"
      }
    ],
    "has_permission": true
  }
]
```

I would like to have the has_permission field inside the object in the permissions array.

Could someone help merge that field with the object?

Thank you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to add has_permission to the json subrecord?

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, data.permissions
FROM groups g
RIGHT JOIN groups_permissions gp ON gp.group_id = g.id
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT p.id, array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(p.*, gp.has_permission)))
FROM permissions p
GROUP BY p.id) AS data (id, permissions) ON (gp.permission_id = data.id)
WHERE g.id=1
```

Comment: Hi Fabian! I tried this, but I got this error: QueryFailedError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"gp\"\n    at new QueryFailedError